# List Schema, change the direction from LTR (default) to RTL Quick Edit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, quick-launch

How can I change the view of Quick Edit from LTR to RTF. I tried using CSS. but it messes up the cells. The edit box are not appearing.

Then I saw "List Schema" with Direction properties set to None. Maybe if its change to RTL it will work.

Thank for the help.